# Is the function increasing and non-decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

> Consider the following sequence S defined by $S_n = n^2 − 3n + 3$, $n\geq 1$.
> Is it increasing, decreasing, non-increasing,
> and/or non-decreasing?

So, I did the derivation and I have $f'(x)=2x-3$
$x=3/2$
So, the function is decreasing $(-\infty;3/2)$ and increasing $(3/2;+\infty)$ and because $n\geq1$, the function is increasing and non-decreasing, right? I don't really understand what is the difference between non-decreasing and increasing?

Thank you

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: A sequence like $1,3,5,7,9,\dots$ might be called (*strictly*) increasing since $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for all $n$.  A sequence like $1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7,\dots$ might be called non-decreasing since there is never an example of an $n$ such that $a_{n+1}<a_n$, that is to say we always have $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$.  All strictly increasing sequences are also non-decreasing.  Some non-decreasing sequences are not (*strictly*) increasing, in particular when there might be consecutive terms in the sequence which are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that there is a difference between saying that a function defined on the reals is non-decreasing for $x\geq 1$ and saying that a sequence defined on the integers is non-decreasing for $n\geq 1$.

The function decreases until $x= 3/2$ and then increases. So none of the terms applies to function on the whole interval $x\geq 1$.

However, the first few values of the sequence are $S_1=1, S_2=1, S_3=3\ldots$. So the sequence **is** non-decreasing, because there is never a point where $S_{n+1}$ is less than $S_n$ (for $n\geq 1$).

When people use both terms "non-decreasing" and "increasing", they presumably mean that equal values are allowed for the former but not the latter. (Confusingly, other people use the terms "increasing" and "strictly increasing" instead, so "increasing" on its own is not clear.)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between an increasing and a non-decreasing function is that one is increasing, while the other is simply not decreasing. A constant function, for example, is non-decreasing, but it is not increasing.

It's good practice to try to rigorously show that all increasing functions are non-decreasing.